# How can I run a command whenever a new buffer is opened?

Tags: emacs

I would like to have `auto-complete-mode` enabled by default. For some reason `global-auto-complete-mode` does not seem to have an effect on anything. What I have been doing to this point is manually enabling auto-complete-mode whenever I open a new buffer. What are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'auto-complete-mode)`

Comment: how would I do this so it works with eshell as well?

Comment: replace `prog-mode-hook` with `eshell-mode-hook`.

Answer (score 1):

`global-auto-complete-mode` is not as global as you may think it is. From the [manual](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/doc/manual.md#user-content-enable-auto-complete-mode-automatically-for-specific-modes):

> **Enable auto-complete-mode automatically for specific modes**
>
> `auto-complete-mode` won't be enabled automatically for modes that are
> not in `ac-modes`. So you need to set if necessary:
>
> `(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'brandnew-mode)`

Thus if you would like to have, say, all buffers that are in `prog-mode` or in `eshell-mode` to automatically have `auto-complete-mode` enabled, you'd have to put the following in your [`.emacs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) file:

```
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'prog-mode)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'eshell-mode)
```